# How to retrieve label created by ASP.NET-MVC helper via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
<input type="radio" id="Check" name="color">
<label for="Check" >Check it</label>
```

if i wanted to call the radio button I call it like below  in the script.

```
$('#check').attr('checked', false);
```

But how do I call the label for in the second line. Do I have to introduce another ID there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
$('#check').change(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
    $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').WHATEVER();
});
```

This allows you to keep the exact same HTML as you have.
Alternatively, you can use the `closest` method as described by @kprobst

```
$("#Check").closest('label');
```

However, that "could" be misinterpreted if there are two labels close together. The first suggestion ensures that your calling the "right" label for the input.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rockinthesixstring/w7SWP/) of how I used this to hide and show checkboxes.

Comment: Agreed, I really don't like the `closest()` approach because it depends on the position of the element, which can change and break scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could just give it an `id="checkLabel"` and access it via `jQuery $('#checkLabel')..`.

Or if you don't want to give it an id you could use .closest:

```
$('#check').closest('label')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you need an ID or a unique style or something to refer to an element, but you can also use a position selector like this:

```
$("#Check").closest('label');
```

Answer (score 2):

It´s probaly easiest to have an id for the label element to access it.

Comment: <strike>not necessarily.</strike> - changed after answer was modified.

Comment: yeah, saw my answer was a bit misleading.

Comment: ps: code examples are always helpful in order to get upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yoy can access it :

```
$('#check').next();
```

If you want to access  it only when the radio button is checked :

```
$("#check:checked").next();
```